# Converting a two digits integer in range into a list

Tags: python, list, range

I met a problem that when I was trying to add like '11' as one item in a list by using range(x,y), it doesn't work.(OK, 'IndexList' is just a silly mistake.)

```
def choose_a():
    indexList = []
    indexOf = input("Enter the  the index number: ")
    for i in range(1,13):
        indexList += str(i)
    while indexOf not in IndexList:
        indexOf = input("Enter the index number: ")
    return indexOf
a = choose_a()
print(a)
```

Comment: Perhaps you should describe what you're trying to do, instead of what you think should be done.

Comment: Some *input/output* samples would be helpful.

Comment: `+=` with a list on the left means "take all the items of the iterable on the right and add them to the list on the left". If you want to add the whole string to the list, that's `indexList.append(str(i))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `i` is `11`, the following line:

```
    indexList += str(i)
```

adds two `'1'`s to the list, not `'11'`.

Problems I noticed:

1. Use

   ```
   indexList.append(str(i))
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   indexList += str(i)
   ```
2. In the while loop, use `str(indexOf)`.
3. Fix a typo in the `while` line. `IndexList` -> `indexList`

Here's a working version.

```
def choose_a():
    indexList = []
    indexOf = input("Enter the  the index number: ")
    for i in range(1,13):
        indexList.append(str(i))
    while str(indexOf) not in indexList:
        indexOf = input("Enter the index number: ")
    return indexOf
```